# How to call displayProductStockStatus() method from a custom block?

Tags: module, phtml, product-view, custom-block, stock-availability

in `catalog_product_view.xml` of my theme I have a block like this

```
`<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="extra.product.info" template="product/view/extra-product-info.phtml" after="product.price.final"/>`
```

Then in "extra-product-info.phtml" file I see these lines of code:

```
    [...]
    $_product = $block->getProduct(); 
    if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()){
    [...]
```

**displayProductStockStatus()** method is used by Magento to decide whether to display or not, the product's stock status in the product detail page; The stock status visibility can be set from the **Admin -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Stock Options -> "Display products availability in stock on Storefront"** backend config option.

Now, how can I get displayProductStockStatus() method from a custom block?

For example, I created a custom module and I added the block in `catalog_product_view.xml`, then I created the block file 
`app/code/{CustomVendor}/{CustomModule}/Block/MyBlock.php` with this code
`

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class MyBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * ProductView constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (is_null($this->product)) {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');
        }

        return $this->product;
    }

}
```

`

Besides, from my template file `/app/code/{CustomVendor}/{CustomModule}/view/frontend/templates/myblock.phtml` I can access the product like this:

```
`<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>`
```

But I can't get `$block->displayProductStockStatus()` because the block class extends `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` and not `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`

any idea how to implement this method in the class?

Answer (score 1):

Open the following class:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php

```
public function displayProductStockStatus()
{
    $statusInfo = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['display_status' => true]);
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_block_product_status_display', ['status' => $statusInfo]);
    return (bool) $statusInfo->getDisplayStatus();
}
```

Now you can check where Magento set display_status by the event. So open the following class:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Observer/DisplayProductStatusInfoObserver.php

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $info = $observer->getEvent()->getStatus();
    $info->setDisplayStatus($this->stockConfiguration->isDisplayProductStockStatus());
}
```

Additionally, you can check how to implement:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Configuration.php

```
public function isDisplayProductStockStatus($store = null)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
        self::XML_PATH_DISPLAY_PRODUCT_STOCK_STATUS,
        ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $store
    );
}
```